# How echo grave accent symbol in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

```sh
$ echo "`"
> _
```

(`_` is input, i think)

Comment: Please do not post images. Rather copy text. It can be copied and parsed as needed.

Comment: @JRFerguson okay i added "text" version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the grave accent. It's special to the shell and is one way (the archaic one) to do command substitution.

```
echo \`
```

As noted by @dave_thompson_085 an alternative is to use single quotes in lieu of the double quotes you used, or to specify the hexadecimal representation of the grace accent, by doing `echo "\x60"`. You can find the hexadecimal equivalents of ASCII characters from the `ascii` manpages.

Comment: Or use singlequotes (but not doublequotes). Or on most systems `echo -e "\x60"`

Comment: Or `printf '\140\n'` without having to worry about which particular implementation of `echo` you have.